# How to fade in a HTML5 dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

How can I fade in an HTML5 dialog? And by dialog I mean HTML5 `<dialog>` tag (http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/).

I tried the following (http://jsfiddle.net/v6tbW/) but for some reason the transition does not work.

**HTML**

```
<dialog id="myDialog">
    Test
</dialog>

<script>
     document.getElementById('myDialog').show(); // note that this is a method of <dialog>, this is not a jQuery method.
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid;
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
    color: black;

    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;

    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;

    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 10s linear 10s,opacity 10s linear;
}

dialog[open] {   
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
}

.backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Use vendor specific prefixes for your transition property as well e.g. `-webkit-transition:visibility linear 10s, opacity linear 10s;`.

Comment: Also, I not aware of any `HTMLElement` instance that has a `show()` method. I think you mean to set the open attribute like `element.setAttribute('open', 'open')`

Comment: Bart: I updated the question. I'm talking about <dialog> element that has .show() method.

Comment: For simple fadein/out effects it's best to just use css3 transitions as in my example below. Note that this is not supported in IE8 and below

Comment: To achieve the fade-in effect, use setTimeout to delay setting the opacity property to 1. This slight delay allows the browser to apply the show() method before starting the transition.

Answer (score 13):

## Minimal HTML 5 version

The example below has the benefit of no dependencies or external script needed. The `<dialog>` tag is handy when opened with `showModal` as it displays a backdrop over the top of DOM declared around it even with `display: relative | absolute` on its direct parent.

```css
dialog {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
dialog[open] {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: inherit;
}
dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dialog.showModal()">show dialog</button>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p>hi i'm a dialog!</p>
  <form method="dialog">
    <button>Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Using a `<form>` with `method=dialog` accomplishes closing the modal without having to handle the close event.

**These two references are most enlightening:**

https://css-tricks.com/some-hands-on-with-the-html-dialog-element/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

**Closing points**

- As of 11-6-2020, Safari in general does not support this
- This makes React portals obsolete for modal purposes

Comment: Just to note, the user agent stylesheet in Chromium as of today applies `display:none` to `dialog` which on its own seems to defeat the fade in.  This snippet works because of the `display:flex`.  I had to set something like `dialog { display:block }` in order for the fade effect to work.

Comment: `revert` is a more semantic choice for the `pointer-events` value on the opened dialog, instead of inherit.

Comment: @Neek that's a bad approach since the dialog responds to keyboard events, check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708671/14098260

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev good point. But, I don't think an element with `display:none` responds to keyboard focus.  Your answer shows an error condition in a different way, with `dialog { display:flex; opacity: 0 }` which leaves it accessible but invisible. Your final fix is good, though :) I'm too busy to investigate much right now.

Comment: @Neek `display:block` does the same. any value different than `display:none` will trigger keyboard events

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I see what was confusing me now, my test dialog is actually stacked on top of _another_ dialog, so when I closed it leaving it with `display:block` it was removed from the `top-layer` but was still blocked from keyboard by the remaining dialog being in `top-layer` :) My original comment was to help people simply using `opacity` and wondering why no fade at all happened, but your approaches are much better.

Answer (score 6):

You can transition the element if you set `display: block` on it (and allow time for this style to be applied to the element).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v6tbW/11/

To do this with `.showModal()`, unfortunately it appears that transitions don't work with only the `[open]` attribute. They do appear to work if you add another class though:

http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/eg4n3x18/

Answer (score 6):

You can consider using

- [-webkit-animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)
- [@keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

```css
dialog[open] {
    animation: myFadeIn 5.0s ease normal;
  }
  
@keyframes myFadeIn{
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

### Eample

```html
<style>
  /*  Optional. change the background style. */
  dialog::backdrop {
    background-color: rgba(255, 128, 30, .75);
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  }

  /*  style1: fadeIn */
  dialog[open] {
    animation: myFadeIn 5.0s ease normal;
  }
  @keyframes myFadeIn{
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  /*  style2: top2center */
  dialog#top2center[open] {
    // Find your favorite style from here: https://cubic-bezier.com/
    // animation: myTop2Center 3.0s ease normal;
    animation: myTop2Center 1.2s cubic-bezier(.33,1.44,.83,.22)
  }
  @keyframes myTop2Center{
    from {
      transform: translateY(-200%);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
</style>

<dialog>
  <header>FadeIn</header>
  <form>
    <button>Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<dialog id="top2center">
  <header>Top2Center</header>
  <form>
    <button>Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<script>
  document.querySelectorAll(`dialog`).forEach(dialogElem=>{
    const testName = dialogElem.querySelector(`header`).innerText
    const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<button>${testName}</button><br>`)
    const showBtn = frag.querySelector(`button`)
    const closeBtn = dialogElem.querySelector(`button`)
    showBtn.onclick = () => dialogElem.showModal()
    closeBtn.onclick = () => dialogElem.close()
    dialogElem.querySelector(`form`).onsubmit = () => false // To stop submit event.
    document.body.append(frag)
  })
</script>
```

- Help you customize cubic-bezier: https://cubic-bezier.com/
- Can I Use

  - [animation](https://caniuse.com/?search=animation)
  - [keyframes](https://caniuse.com/?search=keyframes)

Comment: Those `-webkit-` prefixes are needed any more. IIRC it worked for quite few years without them.

Answer (score 2):

First I've tried [King Friday's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64708195/14098260) and found it faulty. The problem that if you change a closed dialog's default `display:none` you are actually just hide it and it responds to keyboard events:

```css
dialog {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
dialog[open] {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: inherit;
}
dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
Press TAB, the focus will be on the show dialog button
<br>
Then press TAB again, the focus will be on the dialog close button, and its `keyup` listener will be triggered
<br>

<button id="$open" onclick="dialog.showModal()">show dialog</button>
<dialog id="dialog">
  <p>hi i'm a dialog!</p>
  <form method="dialog">
    <button onkeyup="alert('OOPS, the hidden dialog works!')">Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
<script>setTimeout(()=>$open.focus(),100)</script>
```

So to my answer:

A dialog transitions from `display:none` to `display:block` on the opening and that ruins `transition`. The idea was to add `dialog { display:block; }` but it turned out bad because the dialog is just hidden and reacts to the keyboard TAB navigation for example... So we need to keep a closed dialog `display:none`.

So a couple of solutions:

1. You could use `animation` which I like since it's a pure CSS solution:

```
dialog[open] {
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

document.querySelector("#open-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});
document.querySelector("#close-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

dialog[open] {
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein{
  0%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity:1;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="open-button">Open Dialog Element</button>

<dialog>
  <button id="close-button">Close Dialog Element</button>
</dialog>
```

2. You could also add a CSS class after the opening with `setTimeout` to allow the DOM to be re-rendered and remove it on the closing with your `transition` left intact.

```
setTimeout(()=>dialog.classList.add('open'));
dialog.addEventListener('close', () => dialog.classList.remove('open'));
```

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

dialog.addEventListener('close', () => dialog.classList.remove('open'));

document.querySelector("#open-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
  setTimeout(()=>dialog.classList.add('open'));
});

document.querySelector("#close-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in, background-color 2s ease-in;
}

dialog.open {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="open-button">Open Dialog Element</button>

<dialog>
  <button id="close-button">Close Dialog Element</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: thanks @alexander-nenashev I did not see this until recently. You bring up a good point and a good solution. I've been using chatgpt so much, i don't look here anymore. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Fade in and out example

This example uses a combination of CSS animation and the Javascript [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) to achieve a fade in and fade out without disrupting the intended display properties of the dialog.

On the fade in, use a CSS animation to give the dialog opacity and translate, or whichever effect is desired, by applying the animation to the `dialog[open]` selector.

On close, create a new `Animation` and reverse the original animation with a `KeyFrameEffect`.  Play the animation and listen for the finish event, and call the modal `close` function inside the finish event handler.

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog")
const open = document.querySelector("#open")
const close = document.querySelector("#close")

open.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.showModal())
close.addEventListener("click", handleClose)

function handleClose() {
  const keyFrame = new KeyframeEffect(
    dialog, 
    [{ translate: "0 -100%", opacity: "0" }], 
    { duration: 500, easing: "ease", direction: "normal" }
  )

  const animation = new Animation(keyFrame, document.timeline)
  animation.play()
  animation.onfinish = () => dialog.close()
}
```

```css
dialog[open] {
  animation: modal-in 500ms forwards ease;
}

@keyframes modal-in {
  from {
    translate: 0 -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<button id="open">Open dialog</button>

<dialog>
  <p>Animated open and close</p>
  <button id="close">Close dialog</button>
</dialog>
```

**Side note**

I was unable to transition or animate the `::backdrop` in any way.  That is the last piece I was unable to solve.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using jQuery. This is an easier approch:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6tbW/3/

**HTML**

```
<dialog id="myDialog">
    Test
</dialog>
```

**CSS**

```
dialog {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid;
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
    color: black;

    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    width: fit-content;

    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('#myDialog').fadeIn(10000);

});
```

Comment: Actually, if you keep the transition (prefixed!) in CSS and then use `$('#myDialog').css(opacity,1);` it will accomplish the same effect, but hardware accelerated with CSS3. Now you can even leave jQuery out of the picture and do `document.getElementById('myDialog').style.opacity = 1;` and it will still work.

Comment: @somethinghere Cool approach! But since he's already using jQuery and may need it for other stuff, this was the easiest solution I could think off.

Comment: Niklas: Yes, I know about `fadeIn()` method. I would like to use the native method `dialog.show()` and CSS3 transitions. jQuery should not be necessary.

Comment: @MartyIX I'm not sure about the `show()` method. I'm also pretty sure most browsers would't support this as you're really living on the cutting edge with no fallbacks for even an outdated version of a non-IE browser. I'd even recommend not using these semantically special elements right now, so most of your stuff would work way back with only minor adjustments... [EDIT] According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog the method you're looking for is `showModal`.

Comment: @somethinghere: It is a new feature that was released in Chrome 36: http://www.chromestatus.com/features/5770237022568448; demo with API: http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/

Comment: @MartyIX Actually, according to both the articles (what you posted and the one I found on MDN) the method is `showModal()` and not `show()`. Did that help (Also, interesting stuff, the cutting edge :) )

Comment: somethinghere: Actually no, `show()` and `showModal()` behave differently. `show()` displays a window that is _not_ modal.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a working example of using css transition that you started with
and proper jquery selector, that adds the "no-ninja" class to your DIV,
on window load event:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6tbW/6/

html:

```
<dialog id="myDialog">
 Test
</dialog>
```

css:

```
dialog {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0; right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 border: solid;
 padding: 1em;
 background: red;
 color: black;
 dispaly:block;

 width: -moz-fit-content;
 width: -webkit-fit-content;
 width: fit-content;

 height: -moz-fit-content;
 height: -webkit-fit-content;
 height: fit-content;

 /*visibility:hidden;*/
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 10s linear;
}

dialog[open] {   
 visibility:visible;
 opacity:1;
 transition-delay:0s;
} 

.backdrop {
 position: fixed;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.no-ninja{
  opacity:1;
}
```

js:

```
$("#myDialog").addClass('no-ninja');
```